# Scipy/Numpy: summation over multiple indices

Tags: arrays, numpy, sum, scipy, nested-loops

Suppose I have an expression of which I need to find the sum:

[image]

where the bounds are finite and known. What is the fastest or most efficient way to go about calculating such a sum in scipy/numpy. It could be done with nested for loops, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
np.dot(x[:amax], np.cumsum(y[:amax] * np.sum(z[cmin:cmax])))
```

Answer (score 2):

`np.einsum` may be an option too for these kind of sum. As nevsan showed though, for `b` which is bounded by `a` you need to use `np.cumsum` first, and `np.einsum` should not be faster in the given example.

it could look like this:

```
 y_acc = np.add.accumulate(y[:amax]) # same as cumsum
 result = np.einsum('i,i,j->', x[:amax], y_acc, z[cmin:cmax])
```

However this is increadibly slow, because einsum does not optimize the fact that the `z` summation only needs to be done once, so you need to reformulate it by hand:

```
result = np.einsum('i,i->', x[:amax], y_summed) * z[cmin:cmax].sum()
```

Which should in this case however should be slower then nevsan's `np.dot` based approach, since `dot` should normally be better optimized (ie. `np.einsum(ii->, a, b)` is slower then `np.dot(a, b)`). However if you have more arrays to sum over, it may be a nice option.